# How to get token from new smart contract to my erc20 wallet

Tags: contract-development

I created a token using tokenfactory.surge.sh & metamask, but I don't know how to send it to my wallet. Token factory (tokenfactory.surge.sh) doesn't appear to be allowing me to send it right now through their system, so is it possible to send the token directly from metamask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add custom token on your metamask account then you can send your token to any address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Ha DANG's answer:

The code seems to be ok and you, the sender (0x3713d98708c6c3b7df0a24e6544c02dd812f24dd) already have all the tokens. You can see this by checking the `balanceOf` function at https://etherscan.io/address/0x5804b46134c2baf92174ed64f7b13a7ba883f2ad#readContract for the above address.

If you want the tokens to be sent somewhere else, you have to do as Ha DANG said and transfer them.

As a general rule, you shouldn't publish things to the main net without first testing them in testnets (for example Ropsten or Rinkeby). Playing around with your code in testnets gives you a lot of information about how everything works.